# Converting time & timezone into UTC

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I feel like this has been asked before, but none of the solutions have so far worked for me.

Due to using Heroku I am also tied down to Postgres (at the moment)

I'm storing a booking which holds a time and a timezone.

I then need to convert that time into UTC so that I can perform functions with it at the appropriate time

So I have `@booking.arrival_date` and `@booking.time_zone`

My solution so far has been:

```
Time.zone = @booking.time_zone

  arrival_date = Time.zone.parse @booking.arrival_date.to_s
  @booking.arrival_date = arrival_date.utc

  @booking.save
```

But this isn't working. EDIT: **Currently the value is staying in the time selected by the user (and not converted to UTC)**

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: "This isn't working" doesn't tell us anything about what's actually happening. What is your input? What's the expected output? What's the actual output? You should also consider difficult issues such as when the local time is ambiguous or skipped due to daylight saving transitions.

Comment: Hey, I've added the edit to show what's happening at the moment. Also, I have about 6 hours to play with, so I can worry about daylight savings and other things at a later date (if at all)

Comment: We still don't know what the value of `Time.zone` is, or basically any samples. If you could produce a short but complete Ruby script showing the problem - without anything else being involved - that would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to write any code at all. Look up in `config/application.rb` what you've set the application time zone to be. The default is UTC, and you should leave it that way. Also look up the Postgres default time zone. If you're on Heroku that should be UTC too.

Since this is Rails, your columns are most likely `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Then internally all your times are going to be stored in UTC automatically. So if you want to run computations on them, go ahead.

This is definitely bad: `Time.zone = @booking.time_zone`. The `Time.zone` value is a global variable and parts of Rails' configuration. By setting it you are making your code thread-unsafe (which might not matter) and letting one request pollute another (which probably does). Just say `tz = @booking.time_zone` if you need to put it somewhere.

Now what you probably *do* need to do is parse a user-submitted time string, interpreting it as from the given's time zone. That's something you'd deal with in your controller:

```
h = booking_params
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[h[:time_zone]]
h[:arrival_date] = tz.parse h[:arrival_date]
@booking = Booking.new(h)
```

Of course you should add some checks for missing values, adapt this to your own code, etc.

Here is an [article on time zones in Rails](http://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2014/04/timezones/) (by me) that might help you think about this more clearly.

Comment: Thank you! I was going about it the wrong way, this now makes sense. Also, I read your blog post prior to asking the question.. but in my frustrations (from the issue) I didn't take it in.